# Chronological data from postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I have a table `Table1` with two columns: `time:datetime`, `address:varchar` with data like this:

```
2018-01-03-11:25:30, A
2018-01-04-14:34:43, A
2018-01-08-06:25:36, A
2018-01-08-11:14:30, B
2018-01-09-19:10:21, B
2018-01-10-10:18:50, B
2018-01-12-23:17:30, A
2018-01-13-06:24:40, A
2018-01-14-15:18:10, C
2018-01-18-13:44:20, C
```

I want to extract chronological data from `Table1` like this:

```
A, 3, 2018-01-03-11:25:30, 2018-01-08-06:25:36
B, 3, 2018-01-08-11:14:30, 2018-01-10-10:18:50
A, 2, 2018-01-12-23:17:30, 2018-01-13-06:24:40
C, 2, 2018-01-14-15:18:10, 2018-01-18-13:44:20
```

can I do that using a SQL query?

Comment: Yes, you can do that in a SQL query.  Have you tried something yet?

Comment: Look for "gaps and islands". Essentially, you are trying to find islands.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks. I tried group by query but I don't have any idea about how to get first and last item in a group...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach using the difference in row numbers method:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY time) -
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY address ORDER BY time) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    address,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt,
    MIN(time) AS start,
    MAX(time) AS end
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    address, rn
ORDER BY
    start;
```

### Demo

This method uses a trick to separate islands of address records.  The two row numbers let us detect these islands, because the row number difference for each island will always be the same.  But the same difference might appear for more than one address.  However, since we ultimately `GROUP BY` both these difference *and* the address, it works.